# WSO2 IS KM JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope

Tags: api, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Identity Server Key Manager (wso2is-km), and at im login to dashboard have message

**HTTP Status 500 - org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#76)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was solve this issue, please check Log Category on WSO2IS-Km change from DEBUG to INFO